# TCPDF Multiple Footers

Tags: php, footer, tcpdf

I am using TCPDF to generate PDF documents. The problem I have is that I am trying to add a different footer per page. Apparently, TCPDF provides a solution only for a single footer.

Each footer contains only basic html code without any styling.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can turn of the default footer like this:

```
$pdf->SetPrintFooter(false);
```

create your own one like this:

```
$footer = 'yau man footer stuff';
```

and then create your own footer function:

```
public function _footer($input) {
    $text = $input;

    $pdf->setY(-15); // or whatever location your footer should be displayed.

    $pdf->Cell ( // or another method like Write(), WriteHTML() ..
        $width = 0, // width of the cell, not the input
        $height = 0, // height of the cell..
        $x,
        $y,
        $text = '', // your input.
        $border = 0,
        $ln = 0,
        $fill = false,
        $reseth = true,
        $align = '',
        $autopadding = true 
    );
}
```

by calling $pdf->_footer($footer); you create your own footer

Comment: Output is a blank page

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom Header and Footer by exporting TCPDF in class and you use that class anywhere!

```
class MYPDF extends TCPDF {

    //Page header
    public function Header() {
       //Header code
    }

    // Page footer
    public function Footer() {
       //Footer code
       //you have $this->PageNo() where you can add conditional UI
    }
}
```

And you can use this class as

```
$o_pdf = new MyPDF([all params TCPDF requires]);
```

I hope this will help you! Happy coading!!!