# How can I use a multiline footer in TCPDF?

Tags: php, tcpdf

```
// Page footer
public function Footer() {
    // Position at 15 mm from bottom
    $this->SetY(-15);
    // Set font
    $this->SetFont('helvetica', 'I', 8);
    // Page number
    $this->Cell(0, 10, 'Seite '.$this->getAliasNumPage().'/'.$this->getAliasNbPages(), 0, false, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M');
}
```

Right now my footer looks like this:

[image]]

But I need a more komplex footer with multiple lines:

[image]]

How can I achieve this?

I tried to solve it with this stack overflow suggestion:

[TCPDF Multiple Footers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26658186/tcpdf-multiple-footers/28323867#28323867)

But I had no success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `MultiCell` with some cell width combination, like this:

```
public function Footer() {
    // Make more space in footer for additional text
    $this->SetY(-25);

    $this->SetFont('helvetica', 'I', 8);

    // Page number
    $this->Cell(0, 10, 'Seite '.$this->getAliasNumPage().'/'.$this->getAliasNbPages(), 0, false, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M');

    // New line in footer
    $this->Ln(8);

    // First line of 3x "sometext"
    $this->MultiCell(55, 10, 'Sometext', 0, 'C', 0, 0, '', '', true, 0, false, true, 10, 'M');
    $this->MultiCell(55, 10, 'Sometext', 0, 'C', 0, 0, '', '', true, 0, false, true, 10, 'M');
    $this->MultiCell(55, 10, 'Sometext', 0, 'C', 0, 0, '', '', true, 0, false, true, 10, 'M');

    // New line for next 3 elements
    $this->Ln(4);

    // Second line of 3x "sometext"
    $this->MultiCell(55, 10, 'Sometext', 0, 'C', 0, 0, '', '', true, 0, false, true, 10, 'M');
    $this->MultiCell(55, 10, 'Sometext', 0, 'C', 0, 0, '', '', true, 0, false, true, 10, 'M');
    $this->MultiCell(55, 10, 'Sometext', 0, 'C', 0, 0, '', '', true, 0, false, true, 10, 'M');

    // and so on...
}
```

You can see more examples of how to use `MultiCell` function in TCPDF official examples: https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_005/